# Ninja forms - how to show submitted data to the user on thank you page?

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I have a Wordpress website and I am using Ninja Forms plugin for a simple form.

I am looking for a way to have a “thank you” page that will be showing a summary of users submission.

What I have managed so far is to have querystring in the "thank you" page (Ninja Forms redirect action) url with the key of the submitted form (e.g. https://mywebsite.com/thank-you/?key=24).

I know how to display data from the whole form (using form id), but I don't have a clue how to use this key to display data only from that particular submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the form's Redirect url to `http://example.com/thank-you-page/?key={form:id}:{submission:sequence}`

The code extracts the form id and submission sequence. Then it gets the fields for that form, then it loops through the submissions for the form, looking for the passed submission sequence and displays it.

This is very insecure code as it allows anyone view submissions.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'dcwd_display_ninja_forms_submission', 11 );
function dcwd_display_ninja_forms_submission( $content ) {
    if ( !is_page('thank-you-page') ) { return $content; }

    if ( array_key_exists( 'key', $_GET ) && preg_match( '/^(\d+):(\d+)/', $_GET['key'], $matches ) ) {
        ob_start();

        $form_id = $matches[1];
        $sub_id = $matches[2];

        $form_fields = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->get_fields();
        $key_to_fieldname = array();
        foreach ( $form_fields as $form_field ) {
            $key_to_fieldname[ $form_field->get_setting( 'key' ) ] = $form_field->get_setting( 'label' );
        }
        unset( $key_to_fieldname[ 'submit' ] );  // Do not need 'Submit' info as there won't be any data in it.
        //echo '<h2>Form Fields</h2><pre>', var_export( $key_to_fieldname, true ), '</pre>';

        $subs = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->get_subs();
        foreach ( $subs as $sub ) {
            if ( $sub_id == $sub->get_seq_num() ) {
                echo '<style>table, th, td { border: 1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; } th, td { padding: 1em; } th { font-weight: bold; }</style>';
                echo '<table><tr><th>', implode( '</th><th>', array_values( $key_to_fieldname ) ), '</th></tr>';
                $values = $sub->get_field_values();
                echo '<tr>';
                foreach ( $key_to_fieldname as $key => $name ) {
                    if ( array_key_exists( $key, $values ) ) {
                        echo '<td>', $values[ $key ], '</td>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</tr></table>';
                
                return $content . ob_get_clean();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having to loop through ALL submissions to find the one with the correct sequence number is ridiculous (I'd love to use a stronger word). But I can't find any better solution, other than to ditch Ninja Forms. Any recommendations for developer-friendly form plugin with a real API?

Answer (score 1):

You can write code to retrieve the submitted data.

```
Ninja_Forms()->form()->get_sub( $key );
// Get all values for a Submission
$field_values = $sub->get_field_values();
```

Look at the [Ninja Forms Submissions](https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submissions/)

I also wrote about [retrieving all submission data](https://www.damiencarbery.com/2019/06/display-ninja-forms-submissions/).

Comment: Thank you! I read your post on retrieving all submission data before and it was very helpful. I thought that passing key value from query string to `$key` would be easier, but I haven't managed to do that. I used Ninja forms Merge tags  for all fields I need to display and put them in redirect action, and then get them with javascript. Maybe not the best solution, but seems to be working.

Comment: I've worked on this for a bit today. The Ninja Forms docs are not helpful. I changed my redirect url to: `http://example.com/thank-you-page/?key={form:id}:{submission:sequence}` and my code extracts form id and submission number.

Comment: I followed what you wrote and understood better, thanks a lot! One question, would it be possible to make the table sortable for each column?

Comment: @KiDo: It is certainly possible but I don't know off hand how. You could try: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp or https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/table/examples/sortable-table/